# Finding if the current instruction is in a loop using java's asm.jar

Tags: java, parsing, assembly, bytecode

Using https://asm.ow2.io/

I'd like to determine whether the current instruction is inside a loop.

I'm confused as to how asm does this as,

1. Backward Labels offsets aren't determined until you hit a statement that branches to them
2. There doesn't seem to be a way to know the current instruction's offset

so you can clearly determine if an instruction precedes or is in a loop, but it could be

```
statement in question
for () {
} // this jump gives you a label with a real offset but you don't know the statement in question's offset.
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

ok, figured out a way.

Collect all the Labels in a set that you receive thru `visitLabel`, and then when the instruction of interest happens, save off a copy of the already visited labels, while still collecting labels in the original set.

When you visit a jmp instruction, if the label is in the set of visited labels collected at the time of the instruction of interest, you know it's a loop.

Comment: Some branch layouts for non-looping code could defeat this heuristic, if Java compilers (or hand-written bytecode) can be as varied as what C compilers do when making asm/machine code for real CPUs.  For example, https://godbolt.org/z/5czvz6Y44 shows GCC chooses to put an `if` body after the `ret` of a function, so when the `if` is true it jumps there then jumps back, to an earlier label.  `call    printf` is followed by a backwards `jmp .L2`, but it's *not* in a loop.  If I understand your answer correctly, your algorithm would false-positive on that.  Perhaps Java compilers never do that?

Comment: @PeterCordes as far as I know, Java compilers don’t do that. Handcrafted bytecode, on the other hand, could create constructs where even humans wouldn’t be sure whether it counts as a loop or not.

Comment: @Holger: So backward branches are *always* loop branches in Java compiler output?  I wondered if more complicated cases like `switch` could ever change that, even if they lay out if/else simply.  Or a lambda that becomes a block somewhere, but is only used once so the block can return with a jump instead of needing a return address?  Probably no, the compiler would just inline it into the only call site instead of doing that.

Comment: @PeterCordes there are no such optimizations in current compilers. The body of a lambda expression is always desugared into a method, so even if an optimization for an only locally used lambda expression existed, it would be straight-forward to implement as an ordinary method invocation, rather than inlining the bytecode. In theory, a `case …: continue;` could be optimized to let the `switch` label point backwards, don’t know if that happens, in case of `if … continue;` or `else continue;` it does happen. However, backward branches still indicate the presence of a loop in these cases.